# How can I output y-cruncher Pi calculations to a .txt file?

Tags: linux, multi-core, multi-threaded

I have y-cruncher running on my desktop. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to write the calculated pi to a specific number of digits onto a .txt file. The program write an output text file with the last digits, calculation time, etc, but I would like to have the file as pure triviality. Is there any way to do this?
http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/

Comment: Ah, yes, that zero answer feeling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about Linux, but on Windows y-cruncher writes files with default names "Pi - Dec - Chudnovsky.txt" and "Pi - Hex - Chudnovsky.txt" right to y-cruncher folder.

Comment: I just ran a calculation and it didn't show in the folder

Comment: You can also specify folder in "Custom Compute a Constant -> Write Digits to:"